# Error in Mysqldump command

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a data base named "mig". it has 10 tables. now i want to create a same database in another system so I am using `mysqldump` command but it shows error.

I entered command as follows :

```
 mysqldump -u root -p root mig >file.sql;
```

This is the error i got :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>       corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
>       dump -u root -p root mig >file.sql' at line 1

I am getting the same error when I use ,

```
mysqldump -u root -proot mig >file.sql;
```

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply try-

```
mysqldump -u root mig> file.sql
```

**Edit**

`mysqldump` is not a MySQL command, it is a command line utility. You must call it from your shell command line. I hope you are not calling this from MySQL prompt.

Comment: @SahilMittal it shown me `Access is denied`. How to get rid of this.

Comment: I was actually trying this from the MariaDB prompt. So the edit made me realise my error... I did it from the Shell and everything worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

When providing password on the command line you should leave no space after -p.

It should look smth like:

```
mysqldump -u root -proot mig >file.sql;
```

Comment: same error when i use , mysqldump -u root -proot mig >file.sql;

Comment: Are you trying to execute that like a query? mysqldump is a command - one should use it on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some tools like `MySQL Workbench` or `SQLyog` to import the dump file.

Free version: https://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/wiki/Downloads

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `mysqldump` from command line, you must have mysql_home/bin directory in your classpath variable or command-line must be pointing to it.

try using

```
mysqldump -u root -proot mig >(abs_path)/file.sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on my local. Open Terminal and execute the following code (Make sure your are NOT on the MySQL prompt):

```
mysqldump -uroot -p mig > file.sql
```

It will ask you to input the password on the next line, for security the password won't be shown.

If you get `Access Denied`, means the mysql credentials are wrong (or the user you use don't have the right permissions to generate a dump), so make sure you have a valid username and password. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump will not run from mysql cli, you will have to run it from windows command prompt:

```
mysqldump -u username -p database_name > output_file_name.sql;
```

If you are getting error on running above command '**mysqldump is not recognized as an internal or external command**' then navigate to < MySQL Installation Directory/bin/ > and then run the command.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem, my situation was i connect from client in local computer to server in SQL instance of Google. Since i read Sahil Mittal said this is comman utilty, i just put in terminal the same command adding -h parameter.

```
mysqldump -h ip.del.host -u root -p database_name > database_desired_name.sql
```